# Linq Query with date range not returning any records?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I've trying to create a Linq to Entities query that selects records between two dates.

```
TimeCards.Where(t => t.StartTime >= DbFunctions.CreateDateTime(2015,1,31,null,null,null) && t.EndTime < DbFunctions.CreateDateTime(2017,2,14,null,null,null))
```

This is my dataset that I am expecting to have returned

```
ID      StartTime               EndTime    
1165    2016-02-01 00:15:00.000 2016-02-01 17:00:00.000
1166    2016-02-02 00:15:00.000 2016-02-02 17:00:00.000
1167    2016-02-03 00:15:00.000 2016-02-03 17:00:00.000
```

But my results are coming back as 0 records.

Any ideas why that is?

Comment: What is the data type for `StartTime`, `EndTime` and `CreateDateTime`? Are all `DateTime`? What happen if you use `.Value` for all `Nullable` types? Something like: `DbFunctions.CreateDateTime(2015,1,31,null,null,null).Value`

Comment: Have you tried without using DbFunctions? Also in this kind of situations you can use SQL profiler (if its sql server) to understand the issues in linq to sql query.

Comment: may be stupid, but just to raise, do you need to do ToList() on Where?

Comment: I would like to add "which Database are you using?" to @Ian's query? As end of the day DbFunctions will be converted into a SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this code, It will give you 3 records as per your need.

```
DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2015, 1, 31, 0, 0, 0);
DateTime endDate = new DateTime(2017, 2, 14, 0, 0, 0);
List<anyTable> listOfRec = dbContext.anyTable.Where(row => row.StartDate > startDate && row.EndDate < endDate).ToList();
```